# ThingSpeak Error on Raspberry Pi 4 Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, iot

So I am currently working on a university project using ThingSpeak(IoT) on my Raspberry Pi 4.  I have already set up my ThingSpeak channel, and have another program working fine that rights data to it.  Now I am trying to write another program that reads from it, but I am encountering a very odd issue.

Here is the code: (I have 'censored' they relative keys so that people cant abuse the channel)

```
import urllib.request
import requests
from time import sleep
import json

def read_from_thingspeak():
    URL='https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/1152832/fields/1.json?api_key='
    KEY='READ KEY'
    HEADER='&results=2'
    NEW_URL=URL+KEY+HEADER
    get_data=requests.get(NEW_URL).json()

    data = []
    for x in get_data['feeds']:
        print(x['field1'])
        data.append(float(x['field1']))
    #END FOR
    return (data[0], data[1])
#END read_from_thingspeak

def check_if_crossed(data1, data2, threshold):
    print ("checking if data crossed threshold")
    if (data1 < threshold and data2 > threshold):
        write_lightstatus(0)
        write_blindsstatus(0)
    elif (data1 > threshold and data2 < threshold):
        write_lightstatus(1)
        write_blindsstatus(1)
    else:
        print("data did not cross threshold")
    #END IF
#END check_if_crossed

def write_lightstatus(on):
    URl='https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key='
    KEY='WRITE KEY'
    HEADER='&field2={}'.format(on)
    NEW_URL=URl+KEY+HEADER
    urllib.request.urlopen(NEW_URL)
    print("successfully written light status")
#END write_lightstatus
    
def write_blindsstatus(on):
    URl='https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key='
    KEY='WRITE KEY'
    HEADER='&field3={}'.format(on)
    NEW_URL=URl+KEY+HEADER
    urllib.request.urlopen(NEW_URL)
    print("successfully written blinds status")
#END write_blindsstatus
    
#MAIN
threshold = 100 #NOTE: this is a default value.  This value can be changed by the user

while(1):
    (data1, data2) = read_from_thingspeak()

    check_if_crossed(data1, data2, threshold)
    
    sleep(4)
#END WHILE
```

So at the end of the program I have it doing this in a loop.  On the first run of the program it operates as it should, outputting this:

```
67.54235
136.22669
checking if data crossed threshold
successfully written light status
successfully written blinds status
```

upon the second iteration of the loop, this happens:

```
136.22669
None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Projects/Project testing/RPI4_test.py", line 58, in <module>
    (data1, data2) = read_from_thingspeak()
  File "/home/pi/Documents/Projects/Project testing/RPI4_test.py", line 18, in read_from_thingspeak
    data.append(float(x['field1']))
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

It breaks.  If I then try and re-run the program it now skips the part where it works, and goes straight to the broken part.

It will only operate properly again if I rerun the program that feeds to data points to ThingSpeak channel

Any and all ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at your public channel and there are some null values in your field1 data.  Why are you reading the last two values? It may be better to put the data in multiple fields and read one feed entry, then parse the correct fields out of it.

I would recommend you use the MQTT functionality on ThingSpeak,  then you can subscribe to the channel and get updates only when the channel changes.